# Tcl pass variable as parameters to function

Tags: variables, parameters, tcl

Using tcl, i want to pass variable parameters to function.
i tried this code

```
proc launch_proc { msg proc_name {params {}} } {
    puts "params launch_proc is $params \n"
}
proc test { param } {       
    puts "param test is $param \n"
    launch_proc "1.5.2  test param" test_standard {{*}$param param1 param2 param3"
    }       
}
test value
```

--> params launch_proc is {*}$param param1 param2 param3"
$param is not evaluated (i use tcl 8.5)

Comment: You can pass only 3 arguments to `launch_proc`, but you are passing more than  (incorrect ?) that. Also, issues with the quoting as well.

Comment: You are passing the string `{*}$param param1 param2 param3` to `launch_proc`. It does not look like what you want. Did you mean `launch_proc "1.5.2  test param" test_standard "{*}$param param1 param2 param3"`?

Comment: Or better maybe `launch_proc "1.5.2  test param" test_standard [list {*}$param param1 param2 param3]`

Comment: Does the variable `$value` contain any value when you invoke the `test` proc?

Answer (score 2):

Tcl has support for this using the keyword `args` as the last parameter in the argument list.

Here is an example [directly from the wiki](http://wiki.tcl-lang.org/1627):

```
proc demo {first {second "none"} args} {
    puts "first = $first"
    puts "second = $second"
    puts "args = $args"
}

demo one
demo one two
demo one two three four five
```

results in

```
first = one
second = none
args = 
first = one
second = two
args = 
first = one
second = two
args = three four five
```

You can use the expand syntax for this as well which makes the following two calls to `demo` equivalent.

```
demo one two three four five
set params {three four five}
demo one two {*}$params
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a list and need to instead send each item as a parameter to the proc.

```
proc test {p1 p2 p3} {
        puts "$p1 - $p2 - $p3"
}

set value {one two three}

# This should work in tcl 8.5+
test {*}$value

set value {four five six}

# For tcl < 8.5
foreach {p1 p2 p3} $value {
        test $p1 $p2 $p3
        break
}

# or

set value {seven eight nine}

test [lindex $value 0] [lindex $value 1] [lindex $value 2]
```

Output:

```
$ tclsh test.tcl
one - two - three
four - five - six
seven - eight - nine
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [`upvar`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/upvar.htm), and use `list` when you construct the params list for launch_proc

```
proc test {varname} {
    upvar 1 $varname value
    puts "param test is $varname => $value"
    launch_proc "1.5.2 test param" test_standard [list {*}$value par1 par2 par3]
}

proc launch_proc {msg proc_name {params {}}} {
    puts "params launch_proc: [join $params ,]"
}

set value {"a b c" "d e f" "g h i"}
test value
```

```
param test is value => "a b c" "d e f" "g h i"
params launch_proc: a b c,d e f,g h i,par1,par2,par3
```